# Twython replies utilizing expanded character limit

Tags: character, limit, twython, reply

Has anybody had success replying to a tweet with a 140 character reply now that Twitter doesn't count usernames against the character limit?

I get the character limit exceeded error in Twython. My tweet is "@username my reply" which seems to be correct and am including in_reply_to_status_id.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Had to remove the username from my tweet text and add "auto_populate_reply_metadata=True" to my Twython REST status update.

More info: https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/upcoming-changes-to-tweets